# Tracking Copy / Paste Between Office Files

Tags: winapi, ms-office, clipboard

I'm trying to monitor copy and paste actions between different MS Office files (i.e., the user copies a slide from one PowerPoint presentation to another or the user copies an Excel chart into Word). Ideally, I would like to log the following information:

1. The Source File
2. The Destination File
3. The Object / Data Being Copied

My current thinking:

Implement a Clipboard Viewer that identifies the clipboard owner window (and the data) when a `WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD` message is received - but how do I identify which window subsequently calls getClipboardData - to identify the destination file?

I'm also open to alternative suggestions. . .

Comment: Can you fake it by just checking the active window at the time of the message?

Comment: Good idea - are there any circumstances in which you could be pasting into anything other than the active window?

Comment: A clipboard monitor would certainly be pasting data into itself, and would not be the active window.